# How can we customize our own hash function for C++ unordered set to gain a specific order?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, hash-function

In competitive coding we face many question where we have to provide the output in an order of input. So, we need to make own hash function. Any idea how could I write my own hash function?

Comment: You want an unordered set or map to be ordered?

Comment: If you can find a hash function which has 1 by 1 mapping, you can then find it's inverse too which will give you the original ordering.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we customize our own hash function for C++ unordered set to gain a specific order?

## You cannot *reliably* do what you want.

But why don't you use `std::set` (or `std::map`) for such a purpose? Look into [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), and read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) (and the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)), for more.

We don't know what is your actual use case, but I might suggest making your own `class`, following the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html), and having *both*
a `std::map` and a `std::hash_map` for the *same* mathematical relation.

```
 class YourClass {
    // incomplete, should follow the rule of five
 private:
    std::map<std::string, long> mapstr;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, long> hashstr;
 public:
    void put(const std::string&str, long n) { 
         mapstr.insert({str,n});
         hashstr.insert({str,n});
    }
 /// etc...
 };
```

Of course, if you are coding a multi-threaded program you'll need to have some `std::mutex` field in the class above to serialize access using `std::lock_guard`....

> Any idea how could I write my own hash function?

### Writing a good enough hash function is generally easy.

Writing a very efficient hash function could still give you a PhD, and you'll find many papers in [ACM](https://www.acm.org/) sponsored conferences on that topic.

Here is a *simple* and *naive* hash function on strings:

```
std::size_t naive_string_hash(const std::string&str) {
   constexpr unsigned k1 = 78139; // a prime number
   constexpr unsigned k2 = 98129; // another prime number
   std::size_t h = 38197; // yet another prime number
   for (char c: str) 
     h = (k1 * h) ^ (k2 * (unsigned)c);
   return h;
}
```

You might replace the bitwise exclusive or `^` with a `+` and read about [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

### Recommendation: study *existing* [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) code

I strong recommend looking, for inspiration, into the *existing* open source code in C++ (including the code of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), both being C++ compilers; or of [FLTK](https://fltk.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/)) available on websites like [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/). You could need to ask permission to your manager to study such code.

### Recommendation : read documentation

I invite you to read the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)), of your linker (perhaps [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)), of your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor) (I like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)), of your version control system (e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/)). If you are allowed to do so, I suggest using a GNU/[Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) system (e.g. [Debian](https://debian.org/) or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/)) on your computer (because Linux is mostly made of open source components, whose source code you can download and study).

See also http://linuxfromscratch.org/ and https://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 1):

... you can't. An `unordered_set` is *unordered*. Writing your own hash function will not change that. A particular standard library implementation may hold an order for a particular hash function and a particular set of data stored in that `unordered_set`. But such code will not just not be portable, the order can change simply by adding more stuff to that set.

If you need to provide some output in the order of the input, then you should use a container that preserves the order you give it, like a `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Since implementations of unordered containers use hash tables (they are pretty much required to by the Standard) with separate chaining with linked lists, if you ensure that the number of buckets exceeds the range of your hash function (using `reserve()`) then it is reasonably likely - though not guaranteed - that elements will be stored in order of their hash value and for elements with the same hash value in insertion order.

I reiterate that this is *not guaranted* but in a coding competition where know you the implementation you may get away with it.

Also, this is of course inefficient since you will either need to reserve a huge number of buckets, requiring high memory usage, or restrict the range of your hash function resulting in collisions. You would be much better off using the ordered containers.